# how to change the file permissions in hadoop file system

Tags: linux, hadoop

I tried to change the file permissions. The file resides in HDFS, when I tried to set the permissions as 777 to the certain file, it is giving only read and write permissions whereas it is not giving the execution permission to the file.

**This is what I tried:**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/BATCH62# ll
total 56
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root  4096 2016-02-12 04:40 ./
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root  4096 2016-02-12 01:21 ../
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 40209 2016-03-10 19:22 processes.log*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   111 2016-03-10 19:18 sample.log*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   144 2016-02-12 04:32 test.log*
root@ubuntu:/home/BATCH62# mv test.log poc.log
root@ubuntu:/home/BATCH62# ll
total 56
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root  4096 2016-02-12 04:40 ./
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root  4096 2016-02-12 01:21 ../
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   144 2016-02-12 04:32 poc.log*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 40209 2016-03-10 19:22 processes.log*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   111 2016-03-10 19:18 sample.log*
root@ubuntu:/home/BATCH62# hadoop fs -put /hdfs61
Usage: java FsShell [-put <localsrc> ... <dst>]
root@ubuntu:/home/BATCH62# hadoop fs -put poc.log /hdfs61
root@ubuntu:/home/BATCH62# hadoop fs -ls /hdfs61
Found 5 items
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root supergroup        144 2016-02-12 04:35 /hdfs61/owner.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup        144 2016-02-12 04:41 /hdfs61/poc.log
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root supergroup        111 2016-02-12 01:29 /hdfs61/sample.log
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root supergroup        111 2016-02-12 00:51 /hdfs61/sample_.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup        144 2016-02-12 04:37 /hdfs61/users.log
root@ubuntu:/home/BATCH62# hadoop fs -chmod 777 /hdfs61/poc.log 
root@ubuntu:/home/BATCH62# hadoop fs -ls /hdfs61
Found 5 items
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root supergroup        144 2016-02-12 04:35 /hdfs61/owner.log
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root supergroup        144 2016-02-12 04:41 /hdfs61/poc.log
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root supergroup        111 2016-02-12 01:29 /hdfs61/sample.log
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root supergroup        111 2016-02-12 00:51 /hdfs61/sample_.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup        144 2016-02-12 04:37 /hdfs61/users.log
root@ubuntu:/home/BATCH62#
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

HDFS implements a permissions model for files and directories that has a lot in common with the Portable Operating System Interface (POSIX) model; for example, every file and directory is associated with an owner and a group. The HDFS permissions model supports read (r), write (w), and execute (x). **Because there is no concept of file execution within HDFS**, the x permission takes on a different meaning. Simply put, the x attribute indicates permission for accessing a child directory of a given parent directory.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3078